# Is there a maximum size for an ajax call (JSF)?

Tags: ajax, jsf, limit

when I perform a ajax-call which loads a part of the contents of a database, it works fine until the number of loaded entries exceeds about 400. they are mainly only texts, and I'm wondering if there is a limit?

the ajax status bar tells me "success" and no error is thrown; maybe there is a server setting I have set wrong?

PS: javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD is set to "client"; should I set it to "server"?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you getting data through GET request ? If so check length of query string. It may have exceeded the limit(limit mostly depends on the sever, normally it is 256 characters). In that case you can change request type to POST.

Comment: Hi, no they are ajax requests (post). The Data is much longer than just 256bytes, is gets up to 500kb...

Comment: any help? it just does no update after it has finished the operation..

Comment: You said it works fine till 400, so what happened after that ? It stops loading? Get developer tool bar opened from your browser and monitor if you are getting any script errors. Try to identify the real issue you are getting.

Comment: the backing bean operation finishes without problems, but then it is to display the data, it just does nothing (ajax also finishes without errors)... So normally the requests have no limit, right?